# Remove a document field before saving in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I'm POSTing a documents to couchdb and I want to remove doc.phone field if that is null before I save.

Is that possible without using _update handler since I want the request to look like: POST /db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, validation functions do not allow you to mutate the document. (it can only accept or reject a write)

However, if you are concerned with the url, perhaps you could use an update handler in conjunction with [URL Rewrites](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Rewriting_urls).

Comment: +1. Well played, arch nemesis. @weng, I strongly agree with Dominic. It is worth learning how to use a vhost + rewrite to `_show`, `_update`, and `_list` functions which feel identical to couchdb but you can insert your own custom magic between the client and server.